# Writing a filter that goes between a charstreams inputsupplier and outputsupplier

Tags: java, design-patterns, guava

I would like to write a grep type filter that takes a Guava Charstreams InputSupplier as an input and uses a Charstreams OutputSupplier as its output. It should only pass lines from the inputsupplier to the outputsupplier if they satisfy a particular regular expression.

What is the correct design pattern/paradim for doing this?

I would guess you would do the line filter like this:

```
InputSupplier<InputStreamReader> ris = CharStreams.newReaderSupplier(....
CharStreams.readLines(ris, new LineProcessor<....
```

and implementing the LineProcessor methods.

But what should the LineProcessor.getResult() return - just a succcess of failure? Should I be using a 'final' outputsupplier in the surrounding function?

Or am I using completely the wrong api/approach!!

A bit of pseudocode to demonstrate the best way would be much appreciated.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

[CharStreams.readLines](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/io/CharStreams.java?r=d5de86dc98b759183762543e3e977743e781d923) returns a `List<String>`. So according to source code it is asking LineProcessor to accumulate lines and then return the result. In my opinion your LineReader can be something as below

```
new LineProcessor<List<String>>() {

    List<String> result = Lists.newArrayList();

    public boolean processLine(String line) {
      if (line matches regex){
        result.add(line.trim());
      }

      return true;//continue processing

    }

    public List<String> getResult() {return result;}

  });
```

Comment: Thanks - but as the question mentions, I would like the output to go to an outputsupplier implicit in that is that the code shouldn't be accumulating the result in memory. The output could be 1GB of text - so I am looking for something that works more like a filter. Also you can make CharStreams.Readlines return whatever class/type you want - it depends how you declare LineProcesser<?>